# Error with function fortify of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, fortify

I am trying to convert a spatial object into a data.frame using the function fortify from the package ggplot2. But I am getting an error. For example, following the exact same code used in [Hadley Wickhan's plotting polygon shapefiles example](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles), I type the following line of commands:

```
 require("rgdal") 
 require("maptools")
 require("ggplot2")
 require("plyr")
 utah = readOGR(dsn="/path/to/shapefile", layer="eco_l3_ut")
   OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
   Source: ".", layer: "eco_l3_ut"
   with 10 features and 7 fields
   Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
 utah@data$id = rownames(utah@data)
```

Everything seems to work OK:

```
 > str(utah)
      ..@ data       :'data.frame': 10 obs. of  8 variables:
      .. ..$ AREA      : num [1:10] 1.42e+11 1.33e+11 3.10e+11 4.47e+10 1.26e+11 ...
      .. ..$ PERIMETER : num [1:10] 4211300 3689180 4412500 2722190 3388270 ...
      .. ..$ USECO_    : int [1:10] 164 170 204 208 247 367 373 386 409 411
      .. ..$ USECO_ID  : int [1:10] 163 216 201 206 245 366 372 385 408 410
      .. ..$ ECO       : Factor w/ 7 levels "13","14","18",..: 7 3 1 4 5 6 2 4 4 6
      .. ..$ LEVEL3    : int [1:10] 80 18 13 19 20 21 14 19 19 21
      .. ..$ LEVEL3_NAM: Factor w/ 7 levels "Central Basin and Range",..: 4 7 1 6 2 5 3 6 6 5
      .. ..$ id        : chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
      ...
      ...
```

However, when I try to convert the utah object using the function fortify from the packcage ggplot2, I get the following error:

```
 > utah.points = fortify(utah, region="id")
  Error in UseMethod("fortify") : no applicable method for 'fortify' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"
```

I am getting the same error for all other spatial objects that I have tried to convert using fortify; even when using code that had worked ok in the past (before upgrading to R's version 3.0.2).

I have R version 3.0.2 running on a Mac with Intel Core i7 and 16GB of ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the problem has to do with the `.Rprofile` file. This is what I have in that file:

```
options(repos="http://cran.stat.ucla.edu")
utils::update.packages(ask=FALSE)
pkgs <- getOption("defaultPackages")
options(defaultPackages = c(pkgs,"ggplot2","arm", "Zelig","stringr", "plyr", "reshape2", "MatchIt", "ISLR", "rgdal"))
```

Whenever ggplot2 loads from `.Rprofile`, I get the error mentioned in my question above. Whenever I take out ggplot2 from the `.Rprofile` options, I don't get the error.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.
After reinstalling the main packages, the error message was still there.

Eventually I realized that a function `fortify` is also present in the package `lme4` that was loaded after `ggplot2`.
Using `ggplot2::fortify(utah, region="id")` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the shapefile and tried your code; it (or rather `forfify`) appeared to work fine on my installation. I suggest you reinstall the main packages, reboot and try again.

```
> utah.points = fortify(utah, region="id")
Loading required package: rgeos
rgeos version: 0.3-1, (SVN revision 413M)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8 
 Polygon checking: TRUE 

> head(utah.points)
      long     lat order  hole piece group id
1 -1405382 2224519     1 FALSE     1   0.1  0
2 -1406958 2222744     2 FALSE     1   0.1  0
3 -1408174 2221195     3 FALSE     1   0.1  0
4 -1409680 2220162     4 FALSE     1   0.1  0
5 -1411068 2219579     5 FALSE     1   0.1  0
6 -1412780 2219001     6 FALSE     1   0.1  0
> tail(utah.points)
          long     lat order  hole piece group id
19615 -1172872 1741373 19615 FALSE     1   9.1  9
19616 -1172522 1740139 19616 FALSE     1   9.1  9
19617 -1172366 1739158 19617 FALSE     1   9.1  9
19618 -1172124 1737840 19618 FALSE     1   9.1  9
19619 -1171788 1737281 19619 FALSE     1   9.1  9
19620 -1171309 1736884 19620 FALSE     1   9.1  9
>
```